# Help identifying cadences and modes in iidim7 - i - vidim - vsus4

Tags: theory, chord-progressions, modes, cadence

I'm a beginner when it comes to modes and cadences, and I want to understand them better to improve my song-writing as a metal guitarist. While fiddling with my guitar today, I "wrote" this progression in the key of E minor (or the E Aeolian mode, if I'm right):

**ii half-dim 7 --> i (Em) --> vi dim --> v sus 4**

1. Could someone tell me what type of cadence occurs between the bars 1 and 2,
   and also between the bars 3 and 4?
2. If I understand correctly, only the modes have changed, because I have only used
   notes from the key/scale of E minor. But what modes are these?
3. Why does the **vi dim --> v sus4** feel like it has been resolved? I thought tension is resolved only when we return to the root/home chord.

(P.S. I feel I've heard this progression before, maybe someone knows where it's from? :) )

Comment: Just to be sure, with "ii dim 7" do you mean F# A C with Eb or E?

Comment: Hi musicamante! With ii dim 7 I meant the notes F# C E A, not Eb. I can't find the right name for this chord, apparently

Comment: @aditya That chord is usually called "half-dim" or minor 7 b5.

Comment: Please use the [Contact Us](/contact) form to have your accounts merged, to regain full control over your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This progression lends itself to a variety of interpretations, all similar, but varying in technical detail. This progression, even more so than others, is highly dependent on context -- chord voicings, melody, and what happens before and after.

#### ii7 - i (F#7b5 - E minor)

ii moving to i as a cadence does not itself have a specific name.

However, it is related to a plagal cadence, iv - i. Although not a plagal cadence it provides a similar sound. And iv - i is built in: the iv chord = `A C E`, and the ii7 chord is the same but with the addition of `F#`. We could consider the chord as `Am6` rather than `F#m7b5`.

A somewhat different interpretation comes into play if the E minor chord is voiced with `B` as the lowest pitch. In that case, it might be considered a "cadential 6-4 chord", heading toward the V chord at the end of the progression.

#### vidim - Vsus4

vi moving to V also doesn't have a special name. The usual interpretation is that vi is functioning as a predominant moving to the dominant.

However, the "vi dim" chord "doesn't exist." That is, a diminished chord built on the sixth scale degree, `C`, would be spelled `C Eb Gb`, with the latter three tones being alien to `E minor`.

Instead, I think one of two things is happening:

1. `Cdim` is actually `D#dim7` with the fifth omitted. That makes the chord `viio7` in `E minor`. The reason, then, it sounds like a cadence moving to `Vsus4` is that `Vsus4` is actually `isus2`. `Vsus4 = BEF#`, and `isus2` = `EF#B`: i.e., **it is, in fact, a cadence ending on the (ambiguous) `i` chord!**
2. Also possible is that both the "C diminished" chord and the "B sus4" chords are a single chord: `B7b9sus4(omit7)`. Written in root position, this chord doesn't appear to make sense: `BD#EF#C`. But with better voicing -- for example, `BECD#F#` or `EBD#F#C` -- it becomes a `V` chord with the `E` anticipating the (unresolved) resolution to `Emin`. This is very Mozartean, placing the tonic below a dominant chord (before proceeding to the tonic chord). (Note: in Mozart's case, the "dominant over tonic" chord is likely a suspension from an actual dominant, where the bass resolves first followed by a delayed resolution of the rest of the chord.)

#### overall mode

The progression is solidly in E minor and uses pitches only from the E harmonic minor scale. However, it's an ambiguous E minor due to the absence of a strong cadence confirming the key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am slightly confused about the semantics: I thought the 'vi' of an E minor scale would be the note C (not C#). I played C dim and hence assumed it is "vi dim". Is this correct? I have not used C# in any of the four chords, so any mistake would be in my (lack of) knowledge of semantics. One can argue the notes belong to the E harmonic minor scale: 1 2 b3 4 5 b6 7 (there's no D anywhere).
Would this change your answer?

Comment: @aditya Dumb mistake on my part. Just to clarify before I update, is it a diminished triad or a fully diminished seventh chord?

Comment: I play the C minor triad with a flatted fifth: C Gb C Eb. I am not including a B or Bb so it isn't a seventh.

Comment: @aditya I've updated to address Cdim rather than C#dim. Please let me know whether or not the revised post makes sense and answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Why does `vi dim` not exist in E minor if both Eb and Gb are part of the E  harmonic minor scale (7th and 2nd)? About voicings: I always associated `i sus2` (played `R 5 9`) as a slightly dissonant chord. Can voicing (`R 5 9` to `5 9 5 R`) as `V sus4` really change a 'tense' chord to a resolved one? What can I do to understand why/how that happens?

Comment: @aditya In music theory "Eb" is not part of the key of E minor, but "D#" is. The pitches are what are known as "enharmonic equivalents", but the theoretical difference is essential to the analytical interpretation. To your other question, the name of a chord is dependent on the role it plays in the music, not so much the voicing. But the role in this case is ambiguous, which is why I offered two interpretations: one as a tonic chord and one as a dominant. These concepts are covered in an undergraduate-level music theory course; I'm not sure where else the might be addressed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I think my questions in this thread have been answered.